# How to use average() in a query without adding it to groupby - postgresql

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, aggregate-functions, continuous-aggregates

I have a hierarchal aggregate that uses below statement

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS public.values_summary_five_minutes
WITH (timescaledb.continuous,timescaledb.materialized_only = true) AS
SELECT variableid, time_bucket(INTERVAL ‘5 minute’, bucket_interval_one_min) AS bucket_interval_five_min,
MIN(Min_IntValue) as Min_IntValue, MAX(Max_IntValue) as Max_IntValue, SUM(Sum_IntValue) as Sum_IntValue,
COUNT(Count_IntValue) as Count_IntValue, rollup(statsagg_IntValue) as Stats_IntValue, AVG(average(statsagg_IntValue)) as Avg_IntValue
FROM public.values_summary_one_minute_1
GROUP BY variableid, bucket_interval_five_min
```

Here, I am using Avg(average(statssummary1d)), so that I don’t have to include it in group by. However, the value is not correct. Is there an alternative to finding the average in a
hierarchical aggregate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `average(rollup(statsagg_IntValue))` directly: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/UXnYiLqb)

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS public.values_summary_five_minutes
WITH (timescaledb.continuous,timescaledb.materialized_only = true) AS
SELECT  variableid, 
        time_bucket(INTERVAL '5 minute', bucket_interval_one_min) AS bucket_interval_five_min,
        MIN(Min_IntValue) as Min_IntValue, 
        MAX(Max_IntValue) as Max_IntValue, 
        SUM(Sum_IntValue) as Sum_IntValue,
        COUNT(Count_IntValue) as Count_IntValue, 
        rollup(statsagg_IntValue) as Stats_IntValue, 
        average(rollup(statsagg_IntValue)) as Avg_IntValue,     --this
        avg(average(statsagg_IntValue)) as Avg_1minAvg_IntValue 
FROM public.values_summary_one_minute_1
GROUP BY variableid, bucket_interval_five_min
```

| variableid | bucket_interval_five_min | min_intvalue | max_intvalue | sum_intvalue | count_intvalue | avg_intvalue | avg_1minavg_intvalue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-09-27 12:40:00+00 | 1 | 5 | 55 | 5 | 3.6666666666666665 | 3 |

Given five 1-minute blocks with the following `IntValues`:

```
(1),
(2,2),
(3,3,3),
(4,4,4,4),
(5,5,5,5,5)
```

The `avg(average(statsagg_IntValue))` would result in 3, since that's the average of individual, 1-minute averages.

The `average(rollup(statsagg_IntValue))` should properly construct a 5-minute block with all of the underlying `IntValues`:

```
(1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5)
```

and arrive at 3.666666666666666

Comment: This works as expected!